# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value error on SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to append a string to an existing record in a MySQL Database:

```
UPDATE `db`.`tbl` SET field1 = IFNULL(field1, '') + ',' + '12/15/16: $50' WHERE field2 = 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, `+` is exactly what it suggests:  addition.  You are getting an error on arithmetic presumably because the strings are not converted to a number (fortunately -- otherwise you would silently get the wrong answer).

So, try this:

```
UPDATE `db`.`tbl`
    SET field1 = CONCAT(COALESCE(field1, ''), ',', '12/15/16: $50')
    WHERE field2 = 'xyz';
```

Or, if you don't want the comma if `field1` is `NULL`:

```
UPDATE `db`.`tbl`
    SET field1 = CONCAT(COALESCE(CONCAT(field1, ','), ''), '12/15/16: $50')
    WHERE field2 = 'xyz';
```

Answer (score 0):

to append in MySQL, use concat not + eg

```
select concat('something', 'something_else');
```

returns 
somethingsomething_else

you can also use concat_ws (with separator)

```
select concat_ws('@','something', 'something_else')
```

returns
something@something_else